# How do I change the color of a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, colors

Here is my code:

```
var hi = "hi"
document.write(hi)

hi.style.color="#ff0000";
document.write(hi)
```

Why won't it change colors?  I keep getting "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined".

Comment: Variables don't have colors.  You want to work with _DOM elements_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`var hi` is a string, not a DOM element, so you can't apply a style to it.  I think what you're trying to go for is something like:

```
var hi = "<span style='color:#ff0000'>hi</span>";
document.write(hi);
```

Another option would be to create the element on the fly:

```
var mySpan = document.createElement('span');
mySpan.innerHTML = "hi";
mySpan.style.color = "#ff0000";
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(mySpan);
```